# estimate for norms

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Phi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable map such that $D\Phi(x)$ is invertible for all $x\in U$. Let $a\in U$. Proof the following assertions:

1)
Show that there existsa constant $C>0$ such that $||D\Phi(a)v||\geq C||v||$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

2)
Show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\overline{B}(a,\delta)\subset U$ and $||\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)||\geq\frac{2}{3}C||x-a||$ for all $x\in\overline{B}(a,\delta)$

My idea for 1): Since $D\Phi(a)$ is invertible, the kernel is trivial. So for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, $||D\Phi(a)v||>0$. My idea was to set $$C=\inf\{\frac{||D\Phi(a)v||}{||v||},v\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\}$$ However, I am not sure whether $C>0$ if it is defined like this.

My idea for 2): I didn't know how to start with this, also because I don't know if $C$ is chosen correctly. Yet I do know that $||x-a||\leq\delta$ for $x\in\overline{B}(a,\delta)$, so it comes down I have to prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $||\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)||\geq\frac{2}{3}C\delta$. Could anyone help me with continuing these proofs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of 1) Let $S^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in $n$-dimensions. Observe that this is compact. Consider the continuous function $L : S^{n-1} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ given by $L(v) = ||D\Phi(a)v||$. $L(S^{n-1})$
is compact and never attains the value $0$, since the kernel of $D\Phi(a)$ is trivial. Hence it attains a positive minimum value say $C$. If $v \not 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, set $w = \frac{v}{||v||}$. Then $||D\phi(a)w|| \geq C$ and hence by scaling $||D\Phi(a)v|| \geq C||v||$.

Proof of 2) Since $\Phi$ is differentiable at $a$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
\Phi(x) - \Phi(a) = D\Phi(a)(x-a) + o(||x-a||) \hspace{2mm} x \in U
\end{equation*}
If we choose $\delta > 0$ small enough then
$||\Phi(x) - \Phi(a)|| \geq \frac{2}{3}C||x-a||$ for all $x \in \overline{B[a, \delta]}$.

Comment: Are you sure that $\Phi(x) - \Phi(a) - D\Phi(a) (x - a)$ is $O(\lVert x - a \rVert^2)$?  The OP's assumption is that $\Phi$ is only differentiable, so that term is, in general, $o(\lVert x - a \rVert)$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks